# How to ignore browser console error for audio source not found in java-script?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var audio                       = new Audio();
audio.src                       = aURL;
audio.volume                    = this.volume;
audio.playbackRate              = this.playbackRate;
```

Here, for some cases source URL will not have an actual audio file. 
I get an error 404 in the browser console, and I want to ignore this error.
I am handling this error by using the following code below.

```
audio.onerror = function(){
    // some stuf .....
}
```

> Q. Can anyone help me to decibel browser console for this error only?

Comment: Can you post the full code which results in this error?

Comment: Also, why do you want to prevent a console error? Wouldn't a better solution be to validate the URL before creating an audio object?

Answer (score 0):

Check `addEventListener()` with it like,

```
object.addEventListener("error", onErrorFn);
```

Comment: Thank you for response, But i want to decibel browser console GET 404 error.